# Preventing an unwanted vertical line from appearing my plot

Tags: plotting, bugs

How can I eliminate (remove) the unwanted vertical line `x = 1` when I make the plot shown below.

```
p3 = 
  Plot[
    {0.5/(-0.1 x + 0.1), 
     0.04/(-0.004 x + 0.004), 
     1.359/(-0.08 x + 0.08), 
     Abs[0.5/(-0.1 x + 0.1)], 
     Abs[0.04/(-0.004 x + 0.004)], 
     Abs[1.359/(-0.08 x + 0.08)]}, 
    {x, 0, 2}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 100}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see any green line in V11.1.1

Comment: I use Version 10.3

Comment: Look up `Exclusions` and/or search for same on this site.

Comment: With Version 10 use `Exclusions -> {x == 1}`

Comment: `Exclusions -> 1` should do the trick.

Comment: Before above users comments, I myself separated the one line for plot into two lines one with PlotRange from [0,0.9] other one with [1.1,2] after that used Show. But this trick is not as good as above suggested tricks by professional Mathematica developers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can duplicate your problem with V10.4.0 but not with V11.1.1, so I think this is a bug that has been corrected.

```
Plot[
  {0.5/(-0.1 x + 0.1), 
   0.04/(-0.004 x + 0.004),
   1.359/(-0.08 x + 0.08), 
   Abs[0.5/(-0.1 x + 0.1)], 
   Abs[0.04/(-0.004 x + 0.004)], 
   Abs[1.359/(-0.08 x + 0.08)]}, 
  {x, 0, 2}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 100}}]
```

Gives

[image: ver10.4]

with V10.4.0 and

[image: ver11.1]

with V11.1.1